# css compatibility issues with different browers and specific safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I made a web page it working fine with all browsers except safari browser( when you click on header menu you will see  sub-menu is distorted on safari) i am facing this problem from last few days my project is hanged just because of this problem.  can you please  help me  solve out this problem?

http://mindcrewtech.com/Templates/

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. What isn't working in Safari? It looks the same (to me) in safari as it does in Mozilla. Also what is that alert message about? "1920"

Comment: The alert seems to inform about the screen width - just minimize your window, reload and get a different alert-message. And btw - I guess it should be "Investment" instead of "Invastment".

Comment: can you plesae  help me  when click on invastment the  submenu is distorted  in safafi